# How to submit a remote form using a php script and get the server response?

Tags: php, forms, post, bots

i need to do a script that every hour (i'm gonna use cronjob), submit a form and check the response from the server, printing me the output. I know how to make remote post requests, but nothing on how to catch the response.
Script should be in php.
Any suggest?
Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll need curl to do that, have a look at: http://guzzlephp.org/

Answer (score 0):

Note: $url is the url of the remote form like www.------.com/??????.php

try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

            $timeout = 0;

            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");

            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

            $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $data = explode(',', $rawdata);

            return $data;
```